# Windows 10 Lenovo Ideapad crashing

Tags: drivers, bsod, crash, vmware

**Problem/Question:**
Laptop is continually crashing, usually shortly after I stop using it/when it's unattended.

**Additional problem details:**
Recently, the computer seems to crash roughly 1 hour after I stop using it (usually VMware Workstation Pro 12 is running with an Ubuntu machine). Crash dumps have pointed to fvfevol.sys, tpm.sys, hal.dll, ntdll.dll, (nt...exe--whatever the kernel is called). In addition, sometimes it restarts without a crash dump like it's lost power.
1)  I tried running Lenovo's Solution Center Lite which has hardware diagnostics from both inside Windows and inside Debian (via their bootable CD) as well as memtest and haven't found anything.
2)  I've run sfc a host of times with no results.
3) I've updated all the drivers that aren't Microsoft/built-in and updated the BIOS/EUFI which didn't help.
4)  I tried disabling Bitlocker after seeing those errors, but that didn't help.
 5) I upgraded from Windows 10 to the Anniversary Edition which hasn't helped.
 I was thinking the problem was possibly related to VMware so I've been working on exporting all my machines (around 12 total) but the computer has crashed shortly after leaving it unattended every time while it exports/runs machines in preparation.
It seems very likely it could be a hardware problem or an issue when the machine goes idle/switches GPUs/spins down hard drives, but all tests don't indicate anything.

**Attempted steps:**
I've tried looking at crash dumps and performing hardware diagnostic tests from the manufacturer. In addition, I updated all drivers and the UEFI. I tried stress testing CPU/GPU with prime95 and furmark, respectively to no avail. Hardware diagnostics don't indicate issues.

**Additional diagnostic information:**
I've attached the contents of Minidumps (three dumps) https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5_N_bmEfTW4VGxDcERqbW5BdWs/view?usp=sharing

"082016-5359-01.dmp" happened while using the computer after disabling bitlocker. I was in the process of getting Windows converted to EUFI boot from the previous BIOS boot when it happened.

"082016-6828-01.dmp" happened while the computer was unattended and presumably updating a VM and exporting a couple others.

Here is a couple of the System event log as well: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5_N_bmEfTW4VFBuc0tBU3NkWDA/view?usp=sharing

**Current theories:**
Problem could be related to hard drive/storage or VMware (VMware is almost always running an Ubuntu VM)

**System information:**

- Lenovo Y700-15ISK (less than a year old)
- 16GB RAM
- 128GB mSATA SSD with OS
- 1TB 5400rpm 2.5" storage drive
- Intel i7-6700HQ
- Intel 530 Pro + nVidia 960m switchable graphics
- VMware workstation pro 12

Comment: What is the question? It's so open ended that I suspect your "question" will be closed for being too broad. Can you be more specific?

Comment: I can't figure out why the laptop keeps crashing

Answer (score 0):

You should do a RAM test, because 1 crash shows code corruption and 3 errors in the kernel exe:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED (ef)
        A critical system process died
Arguments:
Arg1: ffffd10776660080, Process object or thread object
Arg2: 0000000000000000, If this is 0, a process died. If this is 1, a thread died.
Arg3: 0000000000000000
Arg4: 0000000000000000

Debugging Details:
------------------

DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  10.0.14393.0 (rs1_release.160715-1616)

SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  LENOVO

SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  80NV

SYSTEM_SKU:  LENOVO_MT_80NV_BU_idea_FM_Lenovo ideapad Y700-15ISK

SYSTEM_VERSION:  Lenovo ideapad Y700-15ISK

BIOS_VENDOR:  LENOVO

BIOS_VERSION:  CDCN37WW

BIOS_DATE:  05/25/2016

BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  LENOVO

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  Allsparks 5A

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  SDK0J40709 WIN

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  CODE_CORRUPTION

BUGCHECK_STR:  0xEF

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.14321.1024 amd64fre

STACK_TEXT:  
00 nt!KeBugCheckEx
01 nt!PspCatchCriticalBreak
02 nt! ?? ::NNGAKEGL::`string'
03 nt!PspTerminateProcess
04 nt!NtTerminateProcess
05 nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd
06 nt!KiServiceLinkage
07 nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'
08 nt!KiExceptionDispatch
09 nt!KiPageFault
0a 0x0


CHKIMG_EXTENSION: !chkimg -lo 50 -d !nt
    fffff801c40ea3e8-fffff801c40ea3e9  2 bytes - nt!MiGetSmallZeroPtes+ac
    [ 80 f6:00 f3 ]
    fffff801c418d1de - nt!MiPurgeZeroList+6e (+0xa2df6)
    [ fa:b9 ]
3 errors : !nt (fffff801c40ea3e8-fffff801c418d1de)

MODULE_NAME: memory_corruption

IMAGE_NAME:  memory_corruption

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  memory_corruption

MEMORY_CORRUPTOR:  LARGE

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  MEMORY_CORRUPTION_LARGE

BUCKET_ID:  MEMORY_CORRUPTION_LARGE

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  MEMORY_CORRUPTION_LARGE
```

Comment: I tried using memtest86 and Windows Memory tester and neither came up with anything. I did about 2-3 passes with Windows (around an hour) and two passes with memtest86. In addition, I used Lenovo's diagnostic tool and did two quick, single pass tests and nothing. I'll try something longer, overnight, though. That would definitely explain why VMware seems to be related since VMs suck a lot of memory

Comment: memtest86+ for 4 hours (2 passes) and no errors http://i.imgur.com/Cgn60rk.jpg

Comment: also post pictures of your RAM timings in CPU-Z (memory and SPD tab): http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/2aNiT Hasn't crashed since I removed VMware and replaced with Virtualbox

Comment: RAM timings do seem a bit tighter inside Windows than memtest, though. There's no options to adjust them in the UEFI. In addition, I've ran prime95 for an hour+ among other RAM consuming things and haven't seen issues since ditching VMware. I have a feeling it wasn't playing nice with graphics drivers/when it switched between Intel and nVidia (after being unattended, for instance)

Comment: hm 1 dump showed vmx86.sys, so vmware may cause it

Comment: I think that when happened because of driver verifier + VMware. Apparently you can't run them together but all VMware's drivers were ~2014 on a fully updated workstation pro 12 installation